# create oid column in postgres through liquibase

Tags: postgresql, blob, liquibase

The following liquibase statement when run against postgres (9.3,9.4):

```
<createTable  tableName="document">
  <column name="document_data" type="Blob">
</createTable>
```

creates a table document_data with the type `bytea`.
How do I tell liquibase that I want and OID type?

Comment: Why do you want to use large objects? For most cases `bytea` will be the better choice to store binary data.

Comment: I have been using bytea but started getting out of memory errors when trying to store an 80MB file in it: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: out of memory
635 !   Detail: Failed on request of size 87078404.

Answer (score 1):

Who would expect:                                     :

```
<column name="document_data" type="oid">
```

Answer (score 1):

As of Liquibase 3.5.2, blob is mapped to oid, as one would expect: https://liquibase.jira.com/browse/CORE-1863